# (very basic) Java setting a boolean value in while loop

Tags: java

main:

```
public class ElevatorTest {
    public static void main (String []args) {
    Elevator.currentLevel(); // output current level
    Elevator.go(2); // move elevator up 2 floors
    Elevator.currentLevel();
    }
}
```

class Elevator:

```
public class Elevator {
    public static int currentLevel = 0;
    public static boolean validChoice;

    public static void currentLevel() {
        System.out.println(currentLevel);
    }

    public static void go(int arg) {
        while (validChoice = false) {
            // this building has twenty floors and a basement. 
            // Ground floor is 0 and there are 20 floors above it
            if (-1 < currentLevel + arg && currentLevel + arg < 20) {       
                currentLevel = currentLevel + arg;
                validChoice = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You tried to go too high or too 
                                    low. Try again.");
                validChoice = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the 10th line of class `Elevator`, IntelliJ tells me that boolean `validChoice` is always false. How can I get the program to set this boolean to false only when the else statement is satisfied?

Comment: You need to use  while (validchoice == false) - otherwise, you're setting the value of validchoice to false with "validchoice = false"

Answer (score 3):

For your while loop `while (validChoice = false) {` There should be 2 equals signs `==`to indicate a comparison.

The reason why validChoice is always false is because you are always assigning validChoice equal to false.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize validChoice as false before the loop and change your assignment operator (=) to a comparison (==) or just omit it since you're working with a boolean:

```
public class Elevator{
public static int currentLevel = 0;
public static boolean validChoice;

public static void currentLevel(){
System.out.println(currentLevel);
}

public static void go(int arg) {
    validChoice = false
    while (!validChoice) {
        if (-1 < currentLevel + arg && currentLevel + arg < 20) {       // this building has twenty floors and a basement. Ground floor is 0 and there are 20 floors above it
            currentLevel = currentLevel + arg;
            validChoice = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You tried to go too high or too low. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

I think you also are going to run into a problem of an infinite loop anyway, because in the `else` case, there's no way to change your `arg`.

Comment: Thank you. The prof actually gave us the main and told us to write a class for it, and told us not to change the main (it has an arg in it already). So I think I can just make the class simpler and take the whole boolean out

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers provided, consider:

```
while(!validChoice) { 
   ....
}
```

which reads more naturally.

Comment: I like that it's shorter, but you have to read `!` as not, plus assume that "while not validChoice" is more natural than "while validChoice is false" to everyone.